# What's the proper way of calling C++ functions from other classes?

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on a project that has several classes, and at times, I have to call functions from other classes to make things work. I want to know if the way I'm doing it is efficient, or if there is another way I should be doing this. Here's an example

```
class FirstClass{    // FirstClass.cpp

public:

    void aFunction(){
        std::cout << "Hello!";
    }

private:
}
```

Let's say I wanted to call aFunction in another class, I'd do this:

```
#include "FirstClass.cpp"

class SecondClass{    //SecondClass.cpp

public:

    FirstClass getFirstClass;

    // I would then use getFirstClass.aFunction();
    // whenever I want to call.

private:
}
```

I don't feel like this is very productive. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: If you have an object `getFirstClass` and want to call its `aFunction` function, then `getFirstClass.aFunction()` is what you do. It's not different from doing it in e.g. the `main` function as from a member function in a class.

Comment: Hi @Someprogrammerdude, I read somewhere (I forgot where) that including .cpp files is **generally bad**, that's really why I raised this question. Would you agree on that?

Comment: You're right, including implementation files should basically *never* be done.  But you can separate them out into header and implementations: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/89-class-code-and-header-files/

Comment: Yes you should not include source files. But you can put the class definitions in a *header* file that you include, and then define (implement) the functions in a source file.

Comment: A member function is a member function it is a member of an object so you need an instance of that class to call its member. If you don't want to instantiate the class then declare the member function as a `static` function then you can either call it using an object or directly using class name followed by scope operator: `FirstClass::aFunction()`.

Comment: dont confuse compiling and linking with what the code does. You can put all code in a single file, not recommended, but you would see that you can call a method from another class like you can do it eg from main. The actual question here seems to be about how to compile and link, not really the code

Comment: From the perspective of a c++ compiler, the extensions - sadly? - do not really have a meaning. The convention, however, is that a file with the `.cpp` suffix represents a compilation unit, and the resulting compiled output files of all compilation units of your project are then linked together in the linking step. You should not include files that represent a compilation unit, so yes with the convention that `.cpp`  files represent those you should not include them in another file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all why including source file `FirstClass.cpp`?
The proper way is to create a header file `FirstClass.h` and a source file `FirstClass.cpp` and include the header inside the source and in `main.cpp`.

Second: A member function is a member function it is a member of an object so you need an instance of that class to call its member. If you don't want to instantiate the class then declare the member function as a `static` function then you can either call it using an object or directly using class name followed by scope operator: `FirstClass::aFunction()`.

```
// FirstClass.h
class FirstClass{    // FirstClass.cpp
public:
    void aFunction();
}

// FirstClass.cpp
#include "FirstClass.h"
void FirstClass::aFunction(){
    std::cout << "Hello!";
}

// SecondClass.h
#include "FirstClass.h"
class SecondClass{
public:
    void foo();
private:
    FirstClass getFirstClass;
};

// SecondClass.cpp

void SecondClass::foo()
{
    getFirstClass.aFunction();
}
```

To make it a static:

```
struct A
{
    static void do_it(){std::cout << "A::do_it()\n";}
};

struct B
{
    void call_it(){ A::do_it();}
};
```

- There's nothing with "productivity" to whether have a static or non-static data/function member.
- The semi-colon is not redundant at the end of class body so you need t add them:  `class FirstClass{ }; class SecondClass{};`.